# shifting something to the right

Tags: formatting

I want to know how I can shift something to the right. The `Z_2` formula consists of 3 parts which are underneath each other. But the second and third line are a little bit more on the left. How can I shift them more to the right.

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}



Z_2 = (c_{Run_{GV_1}} * \(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{t_{GV_1}} + c_{Start_{GV_1}} * \(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{s_{t_{GV_1}}}) + \\
        (c_{Run_{GV_2}} * \(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{t_{GV_2}} + c_{Start_{GV_2}} * \(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{s_{t_{GV_2}}}) + ...  + \\
(c_{Run_{GV_m}} * \(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{t_{GV_m}} + c_{Start_{GV_m}} * \(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{s_{t_{GV_m}}})


\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The code will produce several errors.

Comment: search this site for the `align*` environment which is part of `mathtools`!

Comment: When TeX generates errors (and this document generates many errors) Then you should not comment on the layout of the output. TeX does not try to generate reasonable output after an error its recovery action is just designed to allow it to carry on to test for errors later in the document, it is not designed to make sensible pdf output.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I thought `align*` was part of `amsmath`?

Comment: @SeanAllred Sure, but as the OP loads `mathtools`, I didn't want to confuse. At user72067: `mathtools` loads most or all of the features, `amsmath` contains.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Ah, I didn't notice the loaded packages. My mistake :)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi -- `mathtools` loads the `amsmath` package, and then redefines some things.  (it's quite difficult to load only part of a package unless said package has been designed from the start to permit that.  and since `amsmath` long predates `mathtools`, ...

Comment: @user72067 I hope you are not the same person as [user71994](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/71994/user71994). (The preamble in the other user's question is almost identical to the this one.)

Answer (score 1):

Your maths got nor clear to me, but you could try something like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
Z_2 ={} &\biggl[c_{\text{Run}_{GV_1}} * \Bigl(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{t_{GV_1}} + c_{\text{Start}_{GV_1}} * \Bigl(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{s_{t_{GV_1}}}\Bigr) +{} \\
&\Bigl(c_{\text{Run}_{GV_2}} * \Bigl(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{t_{GV_2}} + c_{\text{Start}_{GV_2}} * \Bigl(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{s_{t_{GV_2}}}\Bigr) + \dots  +{} \\
&\Bigl(c_{\text{Run}_{GV_m}} * \Bigl(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{t_{GV_m}} + c_{\text{Start}_{GV_m}} * \Bigl(\sum \limits_{t=0}^T b_{s_{t_{GV_m}}}\Bigr)\Bigr)\Bigr)\Bigr)\Bigr)\Bigr)\dots \biggr]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `multline*` might be another option.  first line left, last line right, and all the lines between centered (unless overridden).  no `&` needed.  and by the way, it's usually more appropriate to put the "continuation operators" (here the `+` signs) at the beginning of the continuation lines, unless you're following french or russian conventions.